# iOS in-call status bar doesn't show when activated in the simulator. Is this normal behaviour?

Tags: ios, autolayout, appstore-approval, ios7-statusbar, in-call

The in-call status bar doesn't show when activated in the simulator.

My app has the regular status bar always hidden, is this normal behaviour?

Is my app going to be rejected if the in-call status bar doesn't show at all?

Comment: When you hide the status bar the in-call bar will also not show. Most games also have this behavior. So I think you will not be rejected. But you will never be sure until you submit it to apple.

Comment: Sounds about right. I will look for some regular apps that hide the status bar and check it out. Maybe they have different rules for games etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No it won't be rejected**. If you hide status bar it will also hide the in-call status bar. You have the option to hide status bar and this option also disables in-call status bar so you don't have to worry. You **can** hide the status bar without giving explanation to anyone!